# qt.qpa.plugin Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "..." even though it was found

Tags: pyqt5, opencv

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con opencv y pyqt5 usando estos paquetes:

1. opencv-python==4.5.5.64
2. opencv-contrib-python==4.5.5.64
3. PyQt5==5.15.0
4. PyQt5-sip==12.8.1

Los instale en ese orden usando pip.
Probe usar venv de pycharm, Virtualenv desde la terminal, y Conda desde la terminal. tambien probe el venv de una colega que con el que si funciona en su maquina Ubuntu 20.04. El problema se me presento en Ubuntu 22.04, pero tambien probe una maquina virtual con Ubuntu 20.04 y siguio ocurriendo.

Probe reistalando libxkbcommon-x11-0 libxcb-util.so.1 and libxcb-xinerama0.
Dejo el output de la terminal(QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS=1):

```
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/2to3"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/2to3-3.9' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/2to3-3.9' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/2to3-3.9"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/2to3-3.9' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/2to3-3.9' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/c_rehash"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/c_rehash' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/c_rehash' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/captoinfo"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/tic'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/clear"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/clear'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/f2py"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/f2py' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/f2py' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/f2py3"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/f2py3' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/f2py3' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/f2py3.9"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/f2py3.9' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/f2py3.9' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/idle3"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/idle3.9' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/idle3.9' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/idle3.9"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/idle3.9' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/idle3.9' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/infocmp"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/infocmp'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/infotocap"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/tic'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/lzcat"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xz'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/lzcmp"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzdiff' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzdiff' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/lzdiff"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzdiff' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzdiff' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/lzegrep"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzgrep' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzgrep' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/lzfgrep"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzgrep' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzgrep' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/lzgrep"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzgrep' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzgrep' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/lzless"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzless' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzless' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/lzma"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xz'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/lzmadec"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/lzmadec'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/lzmainfo"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/lzmainfo'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/lzmore"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzmore' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzmore' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/ncursesw6-config"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/ncursesw6-config' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/ncursesw6-config' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/openssl"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/openssl'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pip"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pip' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pip' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pip3"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pip3' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pip3' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pydoc"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pydoc3.9' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pydoc3.9' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pydoc3"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pydoc3.9' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pydoc3.9' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pydoc3.9"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pydoc3.9' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pydoc3.9' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pylupdate5"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pylupdate5' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pylupdate5' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pyrcc5"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pyrcc5' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pyrcc5' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/python"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/python3.9'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/python3"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/python3.9'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/python3-config"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/python3.9-config' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/python3.9-config' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/python3.9"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/python3.9'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/python3.9-config"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/python3.9-config' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/python3.9-config' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pyuic5"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pyuic5' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/pyuic5' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/reset"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/tset'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/sqlite3"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/sqlite3'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/sqlite3_analyzer"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/sqlite3_analyzer' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/sqlite3_analyzer' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/tabs"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/tabs'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/tclsh"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/tclsh8.6'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/tclsh8.6"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/tclsh8.6'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/tic"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/tic'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/toe"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/toe'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/tput"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/tput'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/tset"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/tset'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/unlzma"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xz'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/unxz"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xz'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/wheel"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/wheel' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/wheel' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/wish"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/wish8.6'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/wish8.6"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/wish8.6'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-ld"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-ld'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/x86_64-conda_cos7-linux-gnu-ld"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/x86_64-conda-linux-gnu-ld'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xz"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xz'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzcat"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xz'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzcmp"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzdiff' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzdiff' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzdec"
"Failed to extract plugin meta data from '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzdec'" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzdiff"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzdiff' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzdiff' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzegrep"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzgrep' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzgrep' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzfgrep"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzgrep' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzgrep' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzgrep"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzgrep' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzgrep' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzless"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzless' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzless' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzmore"
QElfParser: '/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzmore' is not an ELF object
"'/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/xzmore' is not an ELF object" 
         not a plugin
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins/platforms" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms" ...
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqeglfs.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "eglfs"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QEglFSIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("eglfs")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqlinuxfb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "linuxfb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QLinuxFbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("linuxfb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimal.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimal"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimal")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqminimalegl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "minimalegl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QMinimalEglIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("minimalegl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqoffscreen.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "offscreen"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QOffscreenIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("offscreen")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqvnc.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "vnc"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QVncIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("vnc")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-egl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-egl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland-egl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWaylandEglPlatformIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("wayland-egl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-generic.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-generic.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWaylandIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("wayland")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-egl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-egl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland-xcomposite-egl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWaylandXCompositeEglPlatformIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("wayland-xcomposite-egl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-glx.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwayland-xcomposite-glx.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "wayland-xcomposite-glx"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWaylandXCompositeGlxPlatformIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("wayland-xcomposite-glx")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwebgl.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqwebgl.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "webgl"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QWebGLIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("webgl")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() looking at "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
Found metadata in lib /home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so, metadata=
{
    "IID": "org.qt-project.Qt.QPA.QPlatformIntegrationFactoryInterface.5.3",
    "MetaData": {
        "Keys": [
            "xcb"
        ]
    },
    "archreq": 0,
    "className": "QXcbIntegrationPlugin",
    "debug": false,
    "version": 331520
}


Got keys from plugin meta data ("xcb")
QFactoryLoader::QFactoryLoader() checking directory path "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/bin/platforms" ...
loaded library "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins/platforms/libqxcb.so"
QObject::moveToThread: Current thread (0x55bcb230baf0) is not the object's thread (0x55bcb29cc060).
Cannot move to target thread (0x55bcb230baf0)

qt.qpa.plugin: Could not load the Qt platform plugin "xcb" in "/home/chopan/.conda/envs/opencvqt/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cv2/qt/plugins" even though it was found.
This application failed to start because no Qt platform plugin could be initialized. Reinstalling the application may fix this problem.

Available platform plugins are: xcb, eglfs, linuxfb, minimal, minimalegl, offscreen, vnc, wayland-egl, wayland, wayland-xcomposite-egl, wayland-xcomposite-glx, webgl.

Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: El idioma oficial del sitio es Español.

Comment: Por lo tanto, necesitas [edit] la pregunta y traducirlo toooooooooodo. Gracias! :)